# Chart.js creating

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I am in the process of creating a chart using Chart.js, however, for some reason it is not created. Nothing is happening, literally. Console is empty as well, even if I use console.log. Below I will show the code and html, probably I can not notice some error. Really can't understand what's the problem. Please help!

HTML

```
<div class="chart">
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="150"></canvas>

</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="./src/js/graph.js"></script>
```

JS

```
function removeElementsByClass(className)
{
    const elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    while(elements.length > 0)
    {
        elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
    }
}

function draw_graph(graph_data, header)
{
    var accepted = [], rejected = [], timestamps = [];

    if(typeof header === 'undefined') header = '';

    for(var timestamp in graph_data)
    {

        accepted.push(Math.round(graph_data[timestamp]['a']));
        timestamps.push(timestamp);
    }
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Verdana';
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle = 'normal';
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#0B6FAB';
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 11;
    Chart.defaults.global.legend = false;

    removeElementsByClass('chartjs-hidden-iframe'); 

new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
    type:'line',
    data:
    {
        labels: timestamps,
        datasets: [{
                label: "accepted",
                data: accepted,
                borderColor: '#0B6FAB',
                backgroundColor: '#CBFFFF',
                borderWidth: 2,
                fill: false,
                pointRadius: 0
            }

        ]
    },
    options:
    {
        title:
        {
            display: true,
            text: header,
            fontSize: 16
        },

        legend:
        {
            labels:
            {
                fontColor: '#C0C0C0'
            }
        },

        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                position: 'right',
                gridLines: {
                    drawBorder: false,
                    display:false
                },
        display: false,
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    maxTicksLimit: 3,
                    fontStyle: 'bold',
                    fontColor: '#C0C0C0',
                    fontSize: 9,
                    userCallback: function(label, index, labels)
                    {
                        if(label !== 0)
                        {
                            return label;
                        }
                    },

                },
                scaleLabel: {
                },
                pointLabels:
                {
                }
            }],

            xAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    drawBorder: false,
                    display:true
                },

                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    autoSkip: true,
                    maxTicksLimit: 6,
                    fontColor: '#C0C0C0',
                    fontSize: 9,
                    maxRotation: 0,
                    minRotation: 0
                }
            }]
        }
    }});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially there was a typo that was shown in console errors (missing a ',' in scale settings).  The other issue is that you are not actually calling the draw_graph function after page load. Something like this will get you started:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    draw_graph(["one", "two", "three"], "test");
});
```